# Why syntax for channel parameters are different? Are there any underlying meaning?

Tags: go

I'm digging around the use of channels in Go, and in [this example](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2) from Tour of Go, we have this line:

```
func sum(s []int, c chan int) {
```

I'm familiar with the syntax: `variableName type` in Go.
But what does this mean? `c chan int`

Is this a `channel` type, or an `int` type, or a `chan int` type? And what's with the weird syntax?

I cannot search for the answer, if this is a duplicate, kindly give me a link to the original post in the comment, and I'll delete the question.

Comment: It's a channel of ints. And it's explained in the tutorial you're reading. Please read the entire section on channels.

Comment: If you think this is weird, wait til you see directional chan types :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: That's nothing. How about maps of directional chans of functions accepting maps of directional chans...

Comment: @Flimzy: oh my, just reading these words gives me anxiety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm familiar with the syntax: `variableName type` in Go. Is this a channel type, or an `int` type, or a `chan int` type? And what's with the weird syntax?

`chan int` is the type. It's just as "weird" as `[]int`.